# Why do we add %s at last of the path of the application?

Tags: python, automation, python-webbrowser

I just started working with application paths and webbrowser module. I wondered why do we add %s at last of the application path...

```
import webbrowser

inp = input("Enter Your Query: ")
query_list = inp.replace(" ", "+")

url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query_list}"

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

[Image for what am I asking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d2xO.png)

I ran the same code without %s and got this error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwfNS.png)

Please Explain...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html paragraph 3

Comment: I believe the`%s` is meant to be a format specifier, as for what its purpose is, I would suggest looking into the docs of the library you're using.

Comment: Also, Please refrain from posting images/screenshots of the errors/code and post **text**